# Are you supposed to perform partial fraction decomposition for a quadratic component that factorizes to rational numbers?

Tags: partial-fractions

Let's say you have to spread a cubic equation into partial fractions. What you would normally get is a linear factor and a quadratic or a linear and 2 linear expressions. My question is, for that quadratic factor ,if the solutions are fractions (for example : $ (x + \frac{1}{2})(x+\frac{2}{3})  $), then are you supposed to break it down to $ \frac{A}{x + \frac{1}{2}} + \frac{B}{x+\frac{2}{3}} $ ? What i want to know is  : if solutions are not whole numbers , do you have to reduce the factor, and why not or why?

And what if the discriminant is not a perfect square and i end up with surds while factorizing? Do i then still split it into 2 factors?

Comment: You should describe more the context in which you are working. If you work in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ then for sure you have to undertake the partial decomposition whatever numbers you have.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net i'm doing integration and i need to split a cubic equation which factorizes to a linear expression and a quadratic expression, in other words, a linear expression, and two linear expressions which when factorised give (x +1/2)(x + 2/3). i want to know if i should use the linear, and quadratic , as 0.5 and 2/3 are fractions, or all 3 factors

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net i suppose R and C are real and complex numbers, is that what you mean?

Comment: I am working with real numbers only

Comment: For that, you can just multiply the numerator and denominator by $2$ and $3$ respectively, to get a desired decomposition.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 but can i really just do that? must i not then divide by those numbers again ?

Comment: $$\dfrac{A}{x+\frac12}\cdot\dfrac22=\dfrac{2A}{2x+1}$$ as an example.

Comment: as the quadratic formula gives you the solutions to the monic equation of a quadratic equal to zero , if i just multiply both sides by 2 or 3 , doesn't that mean that i don't have to divide by the number again because i will end up with the same root anyways ?

Comment: as an example : $2x^2 + 2x - 2 = 0 $ ,

Comment: $ x^2 + x - 1 = 0 $

Comment: $ (x - root 1 )(x - root2 ) = 0 $

Comment: the quadratic formula for both equations will give me the same answers right?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform integration, you have to perform the partial decomposition even if the roots are not integers.

Why? Because this is necessary to take antiderivatives.

Comment: And what if the discriminant is not a perfect square and i end up with surds while factorizing? Do i then still split it into 2 factors?

Comment: Yes... you have to undertake the computations.

Comment: oh okay then. maybe i didnt notice that when i learned about partial fraction decomposition